# Test if an actual function was called with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am simply trying to test if a function was called using jest 26.6.3.  I do **not** want to mock the implementation of the function.  I want to test if my actual function was called.

```
const add = (a,b) => a + b;

test("add() was called", () => {
    add(1,2);
    expect(add).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

[image]

If I create a mock function, I don't understand how that would be testing to see if my REAL function has been invoked.  Obviously, the mock function will be executed if I create it using `jest.fn()` and then invoke it.  Would I have to spy on my add function?  Still missing the fundamental understanding to do this simple task.

Comment: You can use [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Comment: *Why* do you want to test that? Either the function is a collaborator, in which case mocking it out is fine, or it's part of the implementation in which case you just care about the result.

Comment: It's just a sanity test to see if the function actually exists and is executing.  For instance, if the function is in a different file, that it was imported in and it can be used.  

What do you mean by collaborator?  Does that mean it's a helper function or a callback / nested function used in another larger function?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to spy the function add to get some infos about her like when its called... Then you are to be able to do the expect.

You can do this with jest.spyOn.